# The script needs to Derive from MonoBehaviour, can not take parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have project in Unity and also new to C#. Problem is that I got error The script needs to Derive from MonoBehaviour. I understand what does that mean but when I use MonoBehaviour I'm getting tons of Errors like this:

[Errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3TRH.png)

Will be glad if anyone can explain what am i doing wrong - thank you good people of stackoverflow!

Every script is connected to BaseWindow

namespace BlGame.View
{
    public abstract class BaseWindow
    {
        protected Transform mRoot;

```
    protected EScenesType mScenesType; 
    protected string mResName;         
    protected bool mResident;          
    protected bool mVisible = false;   



    public abstract void Init();


    public abstract void Realse();


    protected abstract void InitWidget();


    protected abstract void RealseWidget();


    protected abstract void OnAddListener();


    protected abstract void OnRemoveListener();


    public abstract void OnEnable();


    public abstract void OnDisable();


    public virtual void Update(float deltaTime) { }


    public EScenesType GetScenseType()
    {
        return mScenesType;
    }


    public bool IsVisible() { return mVisible;  }


    public bool IsResident() { return mResident; }


    public void Show()
    {
        if (mRoot == null)
        {
            if (Create())
            {
                InitWidget();
            }
        }

        if (mRoot && mRoot.gameObject.activeSelf == false)
        {
            mRoot.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            mVisible = true;

             OnEnable();

            OnAddListener();
        }
    }


    public void Hide()
    {
        if (mRoot && mRoot.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
        {
            OnRemoveListener();
            OnDisable();

            if (mResident)
            {
                mRoot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                RealseWidget();
                Destroy();
            }
        }

        mVisible = false;
    }

    //预加载
    public void PreLoad()
    {
        if (mRoot == null)
        {
            if (Create())
            {
                InitWidget();
            }
        }
    }

    //延时删除
    public void DelayDestory()
    {
        if (mRoot)
        {
            RealseWidget();
            Destroy();
        }
    }


    private bool Create()
    {
        if (mRoot)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Window Create Error Exist!");
            return false;
        }

        if (mResName == null || mResName == "")
        {
            Debug.LogError("Window Create Error ResName is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        if (GameMethod.GetUiCamera.transform== null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Window Create Error GetUiCamera is empty! WindowName = " + mResName);
            return false;
        }

        GameObject obj = LoadUiResource.LoadRes(GameMethod.GetUiCamera.transform, mResName);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Window Create Error LoadRes WindowName = " + mResName);
            return false;
        }

        mRoot = obj.transform;

        mRoot.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        return true;
    }

    //销毁窗体
    protected void Destroy()
    {
        if (mRoot)
        {
            LoadUiResource.DestroyLoad(mRoot.gameObject);
            mRoot = null;
        }
    }


    public Transform GetRoot()
    {
        return mRoot;
    }

}
```

}

Something like This:

```
 public class UIGuideWindow : BaseWindow
{

    public UIGuideWindow()
    {
        //mScenesType = EScenesType.EST_Login;
        //mResName = GameConstDefine.UIGuideRestPath;
        //mResident = false;
    }
```

Comment: We won't be able to help if you don't post any code. Pick any of those scripts at random and post it.

Comment: Added scripts to it

Comment: If `Update` does nothing anyway you could also consider to simply remove it and only implement it in the child class when needed

Answer (score 3):

Unity Update Function cannot have any paramaters like this : Update(float deltaTime), this is unity not unreal engine:))

To fix this, Remove float deltaTime , and instead use [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) inside the function implementation itself